# for loop and lists, new to python and programming

Tags: python

```
list = [3,4,5,6]
a = 4
for x in list:
    if x <= 4:
        a += x
print (a)
```

#can someone explain what the steps and how I got answer 11 when I print a?

Comment: `4 + 3 + 4 = 11`

Comment: What do you expect `a` to be?

Comment: `a` starts out as `4`. You then add every integer in your list that's less than or equal to `4` to `a`. So, `4 + 3 + 4 == 11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use VSCode or Pycharm you have **Debug** option to understand what is happening in each step. Let's debug it:

`a = 4`

- first loop:

  `x = 3` and it's add to `a` variable that was `4`, so `a = 4 + 3` and now `a = 7`
- second loop:

  `x = 4` and it's equal to 4, so it's add to `a` variable that was `7`, so `a = 7 + 4` and now `a = 11`
- third and fourth loop:

  `x = 5` and `x = 6` and they are smaller than 4, so nothing happen.

and finally `a is 11`

Comment: iam using PyCharm, where is the debut option located?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [3,4,5,6]
a = 4
for x in list:
```

First iteration where x=3

```
if x<=4 === if 3<=4:  
condition True, if block is executed value a will   
a+=x ==== a=a+x
a=4+3 === a=7
```

Second iteration where x=4

```
if x<=4 === if 4<=4:  
condition True , if block is executed value a will  
a+=x ==== a=a+x
a=7+4 === a=11
```

Third iteration  where x=5

```
if x<=4 === if 5<=4:
condition False
```

Fourth iteration where x=6

```
if x<=6 === if 6<=4:  
condition False
```

No more values in list ,so for loop will terminate

```
print (a)  
O/P --- 11
```

Comment: thank you so much, perfectly explained and easy to understand